# To use Gemini-Pro API should I signup first for Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-ai-platform, google-gemini

What is the use of G-Cloud  $300 credit for free. At one end Gemini pro free Plan says

1. Rate Limits:
   60 QPM (queries per minute)
   other Google cloud says
   $300 credit for free 90days

so when i use Gemini pro model api is my credit will deduct or after 60QPM it will deduct or anything else
what will going to happen?
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KCmW.png)

Comment: I am not sure about Gemini billing right now as there is contradictory information. In some documentation, access is free via Google AI Studio. Other places say the requests using the Gemini API key are free. Gemini is part of [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai), which is a [paid service](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai?hl=en#pricing) and does benefit from the $300 credit. I would contact Google Cloud Billing to clarify.

Comment: Ok Please clear my confusion as soon as you got the answer and thanks for helping.

Comment: Please reread my comment. I recommended you contact Google Cloud Billing support.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to access the gemini-pro model:

- Through Google AI Studio, which sometimes goes by the name of MakerSuite or the Google Generative AI API
- Through Google Cloud's Vertex AI

The model underneath both is the same and the API between the two is almost identical, although there are slight feature differences.

Using the Makersuite method has (or will have) [two different tiers](https://ai.google.dev/pricing) to access it:

- A free tier. However, this has some limitations:

  - You will be rate limited to 60 queries per minute (QPM). If you go over this, the request will fail for some period of time.
  - Your data may be used by Google to train future models.
- A paid tier will be available when the product becomes Generally Available.

  - This does not have the same QPM limitations, although there may still be some limits to prevent abuse.
  - Your data is not used to train future models.

Accessing it through Vertex AI **always** incurs a [cost](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/pricing#multimodal) (although this is waived until the product is Generally Available), so Google Cloud offers a cloud credit to allow people to experiment with it. Similar to the Makersuite paid tier - there are no specific QPM limits and data is *not* used by Google for training.

Comment: As I'm using free version of Gemini Pro API form AI Studio and I did not started my free trial of $300 credits, then what if I exceeds 60 QPM (queries per minute) limit in Gemini Pro Free Version?

Will the model will  stop generating or it will run as it is but starts to charge?

Comment: As I said in the answer, "If you go over this, the request will fail for some period of time." It won't automatically charge you